# System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Employee__c.Name

Tags: visualforce

```
<apex:page standardController="Employee__c" extensions="testPage" id="p">
<apex:form id="f">



    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="acc" value="Existing" checked="checked"
                onclick="show(true, false);">Existing</input>
        <input type="radio" name="acc" value="NEWAcc"
                onclick="show(false, true);">New</input>
    </div>
    <apex:pageBlock id="pb1" title="Pg Block 1">
    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
 <apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!saving}"/>
   </apex:pageBlockButtons>

   <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
   <apex:inputField value="{!pme.Name}" />
   <apex:inputField value="{!pme.Address__c}"/>
      <apex:inputField value="{!pme.Phone__c}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!pme.type__c}"/>

   </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock id="pb2" title="Pg Block 2">
    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
 <apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!saving}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockButtons>

   <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
   <apex:inputField value="{!pme.Name}" />
<apex:inputField value="{!pme.Job_Title__c}"/>
   <apex:inputField value="{!pme.Salary__c}"/>
   <apex:inputField value="{!pme.type__c}"/>

   </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>   
<script>
function show(showPb1, showPb2) {
    // Match Visualforce's prefixing pattern
    document.getElementById('p:f:pb1').style.display = showPb1 ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('p:f:pb2').style.display = showPb2 ? 'block' : 'none';
}
show(true, false);
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public with sharing class testPage {
public string Existing{get; set;}
public string NEWAcc{get; set;}
public Boolean radioexisting{get; set;}
public Boolean radionew{get; set;}
public Employee__c pmepme{get;set;}
List<SelectOption> ownershipValues;
    public Employee__c emp{get;set;}
    public Employee__c pme{get;set;}
    public Employee__c emplist{get;set;}
    public String var {get;set;}
        public boolean editSection {get;set;}

        public testPage(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        radioexisting=true;
        radionew=false;
            Employee__c emp=new Employee__c();
            pme=(Employee__c )controller.getRecord();
            editSection =true;
            var= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
             system.debug('erecrrrtrtrt');

                system.debug('erecrrrtrtrt'+NEWAcc);
            if(var!=null){
            emplist=[select Name,Address__c,Phone__c,Job_Title__c,Salary__c,type__c  From Employee__c where id=:var];
            }
            }

        public PageReference saving(){
                        system.debug('erecrrrtrtrt'+Existing);

                system.debug('erecrrrtrtrt'+NEWAcc);
            upsert pme;
            PageReference p=new PageReference ('/'+pme.id);
            p.setRedirect(true);
            return p;
            }
    public PageReference pbBlockRender() {
    return null;
    }
    public PageReference EdittheSection (){
editSection = true;
PageReference pf=new PageReference('https://c.ap2.visual.force.com/apex/test6');

pf.setredirect(true);
return pf;


        }

    public String mypbBlock { get; set; }
}
```

iam getting the following please help to fix it

> System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without
>   querying the requested field: Employee__c.Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can try to do:

1. Try to use the [`addFields()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardController_addFields.htm) method of the `StandardController` class. That will explicitly add fields to the record:

```apex
public testPage(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    ...
    controller.addFields(new String[]{'Id','Name'});
    this.pme = (Employee__c )controller.getRecord();
```

2. Use `this.` if initializing an variable from the standard controller in constructor:

```apex
this.pme = (Employee__c )controller.getRecord();
```

I hope this helps!